# create nested folders in current directory in R?

Tags: r, nested, directory, create-directory

I want to create nested folders, I used **dir.create()** to create say **/test1/project/code/example/**  in current directory

```
cidr <- getwd()
mkfldr <- "/test1/project/code/example"
dir.create(cidr,mffldr)
```

but it generate like

> Warning message:
>   In dir.create(file.path(cidr, mkfldr)) :
>     cannot create dir 'C:\Users\sharmb5\Documents\R script_RR\test1\project\code/example', reason 'No such file or directory'

and there is no creation of folders. If I use **showWarning = FALSE**, now it not giving the above warning but still not required folders are there.

suggest any method to create all these folders all in once instead of creating one by one.

Appreciations to your answer in advance!

Comment: Use the `recursive` argument of `dir.create`

Comment: From [`?dir.create`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/files2.html): *"recursive: logical. Should elements of the path other than the last be created?  If true, like the Unix command 'mkdir -p'."*

Comment: @MichaelChirico I already used that `recursive` argument but it created folders up to **\test1\project\code** not entire path **\test1\project\code/example** which is required.

Comment: @r2evans Then how the last one to be created?

Comment: @Hardikgupta not fully but partially solved i.e.  up to "**\test1\project\code/example**".

Comment: yeshh it resolved.  Thanks to all of you for your suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it:

```
cidr <- getwd()
mkfldr <- "test1/project/code/example"
dir.create(file.path(cidr, mkfldr), recursive = TRUE)
```